# Why I can't insert data in a model from a custom controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, payment

I created a scaffold for a model called "Charge", but I want to insert data to the model from a custom controller I created "Checkout".

I have the following code

```
##routes.rb
get "checkout/pay", to: 'checkout#index'
post "checkout/charge"

## app/controllers/checkout_controler.rb
require "conekta"
Conekta.api_key = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"

# GET 'checkout/pay'
def index
  redirect_to root_path, notice: "your cart is empty" if @cart.line_items.empty?
end

# POST 'checkout/charge'
def charge
  redirect_to root_path, notice: "your cart is empty" if @cart.line_items.empty?

  total_price = @cart.total_price_cart * 100

  begin 
    charge = Conekta::Charge.create({
      amount: total_pricec.to_i,
      currency: "MXN",
      description: "Pizza Delivery",
      reference_id: "sku product",
      card: params[:conektaTokenId]
    })
    #Conekta::Charge.create() runs successfully and return a hash of values

    @charge = Charge.new(id: charge.id, amount: charge.amount, livemode: charge.livemode, created_at: charge.created_at, status: charge.status, currency: charge.currency, description: charge.description, reference_id: charge.reference_id, failure_code: charge.failure_code, failure_message: charge.failure_message)
    if @charge.save
      redirect_to products_path, notice: "charge was created"
    else
      redirect_to root_path
    end
  rescue Conekta::Error 
    puts e.message 
  end
```

in the app/views/checkout/index.html.erb

```
<%= form_tag('checkout/charge, id:'card-form') do %>
    fields .....
    <button>Charge</button>
<% end %>
```

**Update:**
I can reach to the method charge = Conekta::Charge.create(), and it runs successfully creating the payment, but the method can't insert the data in the "Charge" model and save the data. 
When I go to '/charges' it's empty.

Comment: What does the rescued message say?

Comment: The server respond with "Template is missing Missing template checkout/charge", but in the routes.rb archive I wrote to be only a POST request. ??

Comment: `@charge.save` is included twice in the controller code; it should be there only once. Also, do you have the `app/view/checkout/charge.html.erb` file?

Comment: I should leave only the "if @charge.save" line?, and yes I have the app/views/checkout/charge.html.erb file.

Comment: I already deleted the extra line with @charge.save and it's the same, the method can make the payment but not insert the data to the model.

Comment: Could you add the full error trace - from `log/development.log` file - on clicking the `Charge` button? Make sure you mask any sensitive information like acct number / password, etc. before adding the trace.

Comment: check if there are any validation errors for `@charge` object - `@charge.errors.full_messages`